# Entity Framework Data binding

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, entity-framework-5

I set up a WPF and set up my Data Source (as Object) from another project in the same solution.

I dragged and dropped a table (as a datagrid) on the WPF but when I run it, I only see headers and nothing from the database (the database has 800 recorders).

When checking the code behind I see this:

```
 CollectionViewSource playerBIOSTempViewSource =((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource) (this.FindResource("playerBIOSTempViewSource")));
            // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
            **//playerBIOSTempViewSource.Source =  [generic data source]**
```

I have tried instantiating a _context variable by using:

```
private NHLScraperLib.NHLConnectedEntities _context = new NHLConnectedEntities();
```

And adding this

```
playerBIOSTempViewSource.Source = _context.playerBIOSTemp.Load();  (and also tried .Local;)
```

But the app crashes.

I don't know what I am doing wrong or if its something that I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Crashes with what error message?

Comment: Not a clue. Just responds as the application has stopped working. I'm. It able to debug it as I'm on the road ATM.